# Backup NTFS partition with ‘dd’?

Tags: backup, bootcamp, ntfs

If I put an entire Windows 7 (bootcamp) partition **using dd** into a single archive, will a restore still be bootable?

I just received a new machine with both OSes pre-installed, and I want to get a “pristine” backup before booting Windows.

I can’t use TDM because I have no other machine to read it with.

Related but not duplicate:
[How do I copy an NTFS partition to a writable disk image?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/98381/how-do-i-copy-an-ntfs-partition-to-a-writable-disk-image) 
[Backing up a Boot Camp partition](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/21673/backing-up-a-boot-camp-partition)

Answer (score 1):

I use ntfsclone from system rescue CD. It has allowed me to resize my partitions many times. Then I use the installer CD to run fixboot to rebuild the BCD. Works very well across many hard drives

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using [Winclone](https://twocanoes.com/winclone/) for this task.

It's a paid app, but it's easy to use and will create a backup of your Windows partition in its current condition.

Comment: Looks good, but I won’t need it much.  I really see no obstacle to dd, and it’s free.  It should restore the partition to **identical** but I asked in case someone knows a gotcha that I don’t.

Comment: For the nominal price of Winclone, I would recommend that over dd for ease of use.

Comment: “dd if=/dev/disk0s4 of=/Volumes/Backups/Bootcamp.backup” is difficult?  Appreciate the recommendation, but the question is still whether the restore will be bootable.

Comment: @WGroleau Did you attempt this backup with dd? I'm about to try it myself and would like to know if it worked for you. In theory since this is all block level it should work, but would be good to see a definitive answer posted here.

Comment: I did not, but I don't remember why.  I sold the computer with Windows still on it and did not put Windows on the replacement.  The original plan was to relocate the entire Windows partition to the new machine and erase it from the old one.  But for a no-longer-remembered reason, I decided to stop using Windows.